# iOS library for other iOS developers

Tags: ios, static-libraries, payment-processing

I'm pretty new in developing for the iOS.

Is it possible to develop a library where other iOS users can import and use without changing the code.

The usecase is:
I need to develop a library, which displays a payment view where the user can provide their credit cards information etc.

Example
Developer A has made an app, where he/she needs my library to take care of the payment. He/she then programs the app and import my payment library.

The user needs to be directed to our view to finish the payment and if the payment is ok then our library needs to redirect the user to the developer A's confirm view.

Is this possible ?

Any links will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that's totally possible. Check this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-status-library-in-ios-tutorial

Comment: Not only is it possible, it would be appreciated too!